# signalR 500 internal server error

Tags: c#-4.0, signalr

I've been struggling for quite a while now trying to get my console client app connecting to my console server app.
So far i'm getting 500, "There was an error opening the connection .."
I'm not sure its even getting to the server. although it seems that the server is listening
Do you have any idea why it happens?

**Server**

My Hub:

```
[HubName("server")]
public class HubImpl : Hub
{
    public string Hello()
    {
        return "Hello there!";
    }
}
```

My WebApplication wrapper:

```
public class HubServer : IServer
{

    private IDisposable _server;
    private ServerConfiguration _configuration;

    static HubServer()
    {
        RouteTables.Initialize();
    }
    public static IServer Create(ServerConfiguration conf = null)
    {
        return new HubServer(conf);
    }
    internal HubServer(ServerConfiguration conf)
    {
        ApplyConfiguration(conf);
    }

    private void ApplyConfiguration(ServerConfiguration conf)
    {
        _configuration = conf ?? new ServerConfiguration();

    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Stop();
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        var url = string.Concat("http://", _configuration.Host, ":", _configuration.Port, "/");
        var options = new StartOptions
        {
            Url = url,
            App = GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName
        };
        _server = WebApplication.Start<Startup>(options);

        Console.WriteLine("Server running on {0}", url);
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        _server.Dispose();
    }
}
```

**Client**

My HubConnection Wrapper:

```
public class Client : IClient
{
    private readonly ClientConfiguration _configuration;
    private readonly HubConnection _connection;
    private IHubProxy _hubProxy;
    public Client(ClientConfiguration conf = null)
    {
        _configuration = conf ?? new ClientConfiguration();

        // open web socket to the server
        //Set connection
        var url = string.Concat("http://", _configuration.Host, ":", _configuration.Port, "/");
        _connection = new HubConnection(url);
        Console.WriteLine("Connecting to " + url);

        //Make proxy to hub based on hub name on server
        _hubProxy = _connection.CreateHubProxy("server");

        _connection.StateChanged += change => Console.WriteLine(change.OldState + " => " + change.NewState);

        //Start connection
        var connectionTask = TryConnecting();
        connectionTask.Wait();
        int retries = 0;
        const int maxRetries = 10;
        while (!connectionTask.Result)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            connectionTask = TryConnecting();
            connectionTask.Wait();

            retries++;
            if (retries == maxRetries) break;
        }

    }

    private Task<bool> TryConnecting()
    {
        return _connection.Start().ContinueWith(task =>
        {
            if (task.IsFaulted)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("There was an error opening the connection:{0}",
                                  task.Exception.GetBaseException());
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Connected");
                return true;
            }


        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I've changed the server url from http://localhost:8080 to http://*:8080, and now its throwing service unavailable.

I'm not sure what's better? :)

Comment: Are you able to go to the following url in your browser : http://localhost:<port_number>/hubs? Also have you checked in IIS if the service is running?

Comment: Im not using IIS, its a console application, and i'm getting : "Service Unavailable"

Comment: What does your Startup class look like?

Comment: Client:

var client = new Client(); // default url:port is "localhost:8080"
    Console.ReadKey();

Server:
            using (var db = HubServer.Create()) // default url:port is "+:8080"
            {
                db.Start();
                Console.ReadKey();

            }

Comment: I've changed the server default url to "*"
and now i'm getting:

System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve path
   at SignalR.Hosting.Self.Server.ResolvePath(Uri url)
   at SignalR.Hosting.Self.Server.ProcessRequestAsync(HttpListenerContext context)

Comment: I've changed the port number to 8081 and its working, but.. i'm getting:
"you are using a version of the client that isn't compatible with the server.  Client version 1.2, server version 1.0."

is there 1.2 server version ? seems to me that there isn't.

Comment: I've changed the server code to:
        public void Start()
        {
            var url = string.Concat("http://", _configuration.Host, ":", _configuration.Port, "/");
            var options = new StartOptions { OutputFile = "owin.log.txt", Url = url, Verbosity = 2 };
            _server = WebApplication.Start<Startup>(options);
            Console.WriteLine("Server running on {0}", options.Url);
        }

now its getting 500 Internal server error though both are talking 1.2

Comment: You can't use localhost with SignalR, unless you're also calling it from the same machine. Are you using localhost? If so, use the machine name instead.

Comment: did you ever get this working? I have the same problem ... I can browse to localhost:8081/hubs but its just a blank page ... using signalr 2.0.3 now